# Gettign major and minor details while monitoring for beacons

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, cllocationmanager, ibeacon, beacon

Iam using **CLLocationmanager** to monitor for beacon regions. I am feeding uuid and identifier but when a beacon is detected I don't get major and  minor values in return.
I am using [Link](https://github.com/MacKentoch/react-native-beacons-manager).

Answer (score 0):

You must use `Beacons.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(region);` to read the major and minor values.   These fields are not returned if you simply call `Beacons.startMonitoringForRegion(region);`

Comment: But I need entry and exit events for more than 20 regions on iOS, is that possible? And is it possible to get entry and exit events in ranging ?

Comment: You can only get entry and exit events for 20 regions.  That is an iOS limitation, sorry.   You can range and monitor simultaneously, so you can get entry/exit events for your 20 most important regions and you can read the identifiers for all other regions.   It is common to get around this limitation by creatively defining your regions for your use case.   I'd suggest opening a new question describing your use case and current beacon identifier scheme and ask for help coming up with ways to accomplish your goal given the 20 region monitoring limit on iOS.

Comment: I need a way to monitor more and yeah makes sense I'll open a new thread